# Constant declaration with block

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment, gecko, spidermonkey, destructuring

Recently I was looking into Firefox [Add-on Builder](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/builder) SDK sources, and stumbled on such constants declaration:

```
const { getCodeForKey, toJSON } = require("../../keyboard/utils");
```

I could find information about [CommonJS Modules](http://www.commonjs.org/specs/modules/1.0/), but left part of this assignment slightly confuses me, since it must be language specific, and I couldn't google anything on that.

Can someone point me to some specification/draft that explains what's going on here?

Comment: Since javascript 1.7 (in gecko based browsers) a function van return multiple values and the left part basically collect 2 different values. Or well that's what I think based on document found here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.7. On that page they show examples as [a, b] = fn(); but i suspect it's similar as it's in FF extension. Read from the title "Destructuring assignment (Merge into own page/section)"

Comment: see also the canonical [Javascript object bracket notation on left side to assign](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26999820/1048572)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.7#Destructuring_assignment_%28Merge_into_own_page.2Fsection%29), something that is currently only implemented by the SpiderMonkey JavaScript engine which is used by Firefox. Here is how it works with arrays:

```
// Destructuring assignment
[a, b] = foo;

// Equivalent code
a = foo[0];
b = foo[1];
```

And here is how it works with objects:

```
// Destructuring assignment
{a, b} = foo;

// Equivalent code
a = foo.a;
b = foo.b;
```

A slightly more elaborate example:

```
// Destructuring assignment
{name: a, address: {line1: b}} = foo;

// Equivalent code
a = foo.name;
b = foo.address.line1;
```

So your code example is equivalent to:

```
var utilsExports = require("../../keyboard/utils");
const getCodeForKey = utilsExports.getCodeForKey;
const toJSON = utilsExports.toJSON;
```

It is merely a more convenient way to write it.