# explain var {A: a} = {A: 1}

Tags: javascript

I have the following pieces of code (which only parses and runs correctly in Firefox)

```
var {A: a} = {A: 1};
console.log(a); // 1
```

And now we have a variable called 'a' with value is 1

So I have 3 questions to ask

1. Why do we need 'var' here? Why don't we need var on the rhs of '='
2. How does 'a' be in the scope ?
3. How does 'a' get assigned to 1? 
   it seems uses member-wise copy here, but why? 
    
   shouldn't the object on the lhs will reference to the object on rhs?

For example,

```
var b = {B: 1};
var c = {B: 2};
b = c;
b.B = 3;
console.log(c);
```

In this assignment(b = c), b now references to c, and they share the same object. Why this assignment differs from my original one?

Forgot to mention I am testing on Firefox 16.0

Comment: `var {A: a}` is not valid syntax so the code will not run

Comment: What JS runtime are you using to produce this result?

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`

Comment: Though I thought this is invalid syntax, strange enough, it works on Firefox when I test.

Comment: @AlvinWong you should probably mention that in the question

Comment: @kidmenot I am not the author of the OP.

Comment: `Syntax error at line 8 while loading: expected identifier, got '{': var {A: a} = {A: 1};` (Opera 12) `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { ` (Chromium 20)

Comment: Probably related: [Javascript - Assigning multiple variables to object properties using curly braces in variable declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526065/javascript-assigning-multiple-variables-to-object-properties-using-curly-brace) -> [Constant declaration with block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199229/constant-declaration-with-block)

Comment: Forgot to mention I am testing on Firefox 16

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple assignment in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986348/multiple-assignment-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

The code that you have:

```
var {A: a} = {A: 1};
```

Is not valid JavaScript, it will only work when using Firefox and it does not pass any known linters).

As ThiefMaster mentions and after looking this up in the documentation, this usage is called destructuring assignment.

You can read about it here: [Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7#Destructuring_assignment_%28Merge_into_own_page.2Fsection%29)

Taken from the page.

You can use destructuring assignment, for example, to swap values:

```
var a = 1;
var b = 3;

[a, b] = [b, a];
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. This fails all linters though. It's not valid JS. I'm looking into this on FF now.

Comment: It's called destructuring assignment and a mozilla-specific JS extension.