# Javascript object bracket notation ({ Navigation } =) on left side of assign

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I haven't seen this syntax before and am wondering what it's all about.

```
var { Navigation } = require('react-router');
```

The brackets on the left are throwing a syntax error:

> unexpected token {

I'm not sure what part of the webpack config is transforming or what the purpose of the syntax is. Is it a Harmony thing? Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: In your `webpack.config.js` you probably have [`jsx-loader`](https://github.com/petehunt/jsx-loader) with the `harmony` flag enabled

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does curly brackets in the \`var { ... } = ...\` statements do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15290981/what-does-curly-brackets-in-the-var-statements-do)

Answer (score 143, accepted):

It's called [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and it's part of the [ES2015 standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/).

> The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that
>   makes it possible to extract data from arrays or objects using a
>   syntax that mirrors the construction of array and object literals.
>
> *Source:* *[Destructuring assignment reference on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)*

## Object destructuring

```
 var o = {p: 42, q: true};
 var {p, q} = o;

 console.log(p); // 42
 console.log(q); // true 

 // Assign new variable names
 var {p: foo, q: bar} = o;

 console.log(foo); // 42
 console.log(bar); // true
```

## Array destructuring

```
var foo = ["one", "two", "three"];

// without destructuring
var one   = foo[0];
var two   = foo[1];
var three = foo[2];

// with destructuring
var [one, two, three] = foo;
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to accept this and pose another question. Now that I know what what the syntax is I have to figure out what it's still not compiling in my project.

Comment: Webpack uses Esprima and will [have support for es6 when Esprima 2.0 is published](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/532). Until then you can use one of the es6-loader which compile it down to es5: https://github.com/conradz/esnext-loader https://github.com/Couto/6to5-loader https://github.com/shama/es6-loader

Comment: I downvoted this solution because it failed to address the example he gave which is not shown in the solution. The first example shows an object literal being destructured. The second shows an array being destructured. But the example being questioned is this: var { Navigation } = require('react-router'); Furthermore, in the example he gave, the braces are unnecessary.

Comment: @AndroidDev you're welcome to suggest an edit; the OP certainly seemed to find the answer satisfactory.

Comment: Any idea why the [re]naming is "backwards"? That is, `var {newVarName: oldVarName} = varSource;` looks a lot like `{ newVarName: varSource.oldVarName }` or `scope.newVarName = varSource.oldVarName;`, but those are, obviously, wrong. Is there a practical reason for having the old/existing names on the left of the `:`?

Comment: @ruffin you shouldn't think of it like an object declaration where you have name:value pairs (what you would describe as "forward"). Object deconstruction is more like a restricted **with** statement block where you access only a subset of an objects properties. Objects supplied by system (and like) modules tend to have nice, descriptive but rather long (and sometimes conflicting with other objects' property) names so the syntax allows the declaration to optionally include an alias for the property name. So a better way to look at the syntax is ```PropertyName [ ":" Alias ]```

Answer (score 122):

This is [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). It's a new feature of ECMAScript 2015.

```
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} = React;
```

Is the equivalent to:

```
var AppRegistry = React.AppRegistry;
var StyleSheet = React.StyleSheet;
var Text = React.Text;
var View = React.View;
```

Answer (score 26):

```
var { Navigation } = require('react-router');
```

... uses destructuring to achieve the same thing as ...

```
var Navigation = require('react-router').Navigation;
```

... but is far more readable.

Comment: This directly answers the question as asked and so is probably the best answer to read first, while some of the earlier answers go into more depth.

Comment: More concise...yes. More readable - not really.  The latter example is more explicit using more fundamental constructs, therefor is more readable - but for an expert, the former is more efficient.

Answer (score 9):

It's a new feature in ES6 to destructure objects.

As we all know that there is an assignment operation taking place here, which means right side value is getting assigned to left side variable.

```
var { Navigation } = require('react-router');
```

In this case `require('react-router')` method returns an object with key-value pair, something like:

```
{ Navigation: function a(){}, 
Example1: function b(){},
 Example2: function c(){}
}
```

And if we would like to take one key in that returned object say `Navigation` to a variable we can use [Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for that.

This will only be possible only if we have the key in hand.

So after the assignment statement, local variable `Navigation` will contain `function a(){}`

Another example looks like this.

```
var { p, q } = { p: 1, q:2, r:3, s:4 };
console.log(p) //1;
console.log(q) //2;
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of

```
const salary = personnel.salary
const sex = personnel.sex
const age = personnel.age
```

simply

```
const {salary, age, sex} = personnel
```