# I don't understand what this const expression does in ReactJs / ECMAScript6

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I see this in facebook's fixed-data-table reactjs ui example code (written in ECMAScript6):

```
const {Table, Column, Cell} = FixedDataTable;
```

I used const before, but all the ECMA6 documentation and reactjs that I can find does not explain what the code snippet above exactly does. The syntax doesn't make sense to me, yet it clearly is important because without it I can't use FixedDataTable react class, and the snippet below does not render the UI:

```
                <Table rowHeight={50}
                       rowsCount={rows.length}
                       width={500}
                       height={500}
                       headerHeight={50}>
                    <Column header={<Cell>Col 1</Cell>}
                      cell={<Cell>Column 1 static content</Cell>}
                      width={200}
                    />
                </Table>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript object bracket notation on left side to assign](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26999820/javascript-object-bracket-notation-on-left-side-to-assign)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [*Destructuring assignment*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) ([*Object destructuring*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring), actually).

After that line `Table` is `FixedDataTable.Table`, `Column` is `FixedDataTable.Column` and `Cell` is `FixedDataTable.Cell`. [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) makes these variables read-only.

It's equivalent to:

```
const Table = FixedDataTable.Table,
      Column = FixedDataTable.Column,
      Cell = FixedDataTable.Cell;
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I didn't know about Destructuring as a concept. Haven't worked with Javascript in depth for some time and ES6 is taking me some time to get used to.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). `FixedDataTable` is probably an object with properties `Table`, `Column` and `Cell`.

What it actually does:

```
const Table = FixedDataTable.Table;
const Column = FixedDataTable.Column;
const Cell = FixedDataTable.Cell;
```