# Why is `(foo) = "bar"` legal in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecma

In Node.js's REPL (tested in SpiderMonkey as well) the sequence

```
var foo = null;
(foo) = "bar";
```

is valid, with `foo` subsequently equal to `"bar"` as opposed to `null`.

This seems counterintuitive because one would think the parenthesis would at least dereference `bar` and throw *Invalid left-hand side in assignment`*.

Understandably, when you do anything interesting it does fail in aforementioned way.

```
(foo, bar) = 4
(true ? bar : foo) = 4
```

According to [ECMA-262 on LeftHandExpressions](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-left-hand-side-expressions) (so far as I can interpret) are no valid non-terminals that would lead to a parenthetical being accepted.

Is there something I'm not seeing?

Comment: i would have guessed [destructuring assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26999862/1132334), but that has only square and curly brackets

Comment: Guess parenthesis just force the calculation inside, `(foo) === foo`, also we have `(true ? foo : bar) === foo;` (both correct).

Comment: It's a grouping operator here, why would it be invalid? You can also do `foo = (5)` for example.

Comment: @wostex "It's a grouping operator here" --- if it was - it would be syntactically incorrect.

Comment: @skobaljic in your example `(foo) === foo` is because the values are equal. However, there also, the reference does not matter. `(foo)` in a perfect world would "return" the object contained, not the `foo` reference to be _overwitten_ by the `=` expression.

Comment: Correct, I voted up your question, wanna know why, too.

Comment: @TERMtm don't know if I'm really on the right track, but according to the specification (the one you linked), there is a second lexer rule to 12.2.1.5 that defines that a `CoverParenthesizedExpressionAndArrowParameterList` qualifies as `IsValidSimpleAssignmentTarget`, yielding its inner `expr`.

Comment: The answer is: Because JavaScript.

Comment: `(foo)` in this case is not a grouping operator, in the same way in which the method call `(obj.foo)()` does not have a grouping operator around `obj.foo`. `(0, obj.foo)()`, in contrast, does contain a grouping operator. The prior call passes `obj` as `this` context to `foo` (just like `obj.foo()`), the latter call does not. See [Why comma operator changes `this` in function call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63737893/4642212).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's valid indeed. You're allowed to wrap any simple assignment target in parenthesis.

The left hand part of the `=` operation is a [`LeftHandSideExpression`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#prod-LeftHandSideExpression) as you correctly identified. This can be tracked down through the various precendence levels ([`NewExpression`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#prod-NewExpression), [`MemberExpression`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#prod-MemberExpression)) to a [`PrimaryExpression`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#prod-PrimaryExpression), which in turn might be a [`Cover­Parenthesized­Expression­And­Arrow­Parameter­List`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#prod-CoverParenthesizedExpressionAndArrowParameterList):

```
( Expression[In, ?Yield] )
```

(actually, when parsed with target `PrimaryExpression`, it's a [`ParenthesizedExpression`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#prod-ParenthesizedExpression)).

So it's valid by the grammar, at least. Whether it's actually valid JS syntax is determined by another factor: early error static semantics. Those are basically prose or algorithmic rules that make some production expansions invalid (syntax errors) in certain cases. This for example allowed the authors to reuse the array and object initialiser grammars for destructuring, but only applying certain rules. In the [early errors for assignment expressions](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-assignment-operators-static-semantics-early-errors) we find

> It is an early `Reference Error` if *LeftHandSideExpression* is neither an *ObjectLiteral* nor an *ArrayLiteral* and **IsValidSimpleAssignmentTarget** of *LeftHandSideExpression* is `false`.

We can also see this distinction in the [evaluation of assignment expressions](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation), where simple assignment targets are evaluated to a reference that can be assigned to, instead of getting the destructuring pattern stuff like object and array literals.

So what does that [IsValidSimpleAssignmentTarget](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-static-semantics-static-semantics-isvalidsimpleassignmenttarget) do to *LeftHandSideExpressions*? Basically it allows assignments to property accesses and disallows assignments to call expressions. It doesn't state anything about plain *PrimaryExpressions* which have their [own IsValidSimpleAssignmentTarget rule](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-semantics-static-semantics-isvalidsimpleassignmenttarget). All it does is to extract the *Expression* between the parentheses through the [Covered­Parenthesized­Expression operation](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-static-semantics-coveredparenthesizedexpression), and then again check IsValidSimpleAssignmentTarget of that. In short: `(…) = …` is valid when `… = …` is valid. It'll yield `true` only for [*Identifiers*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-identifiers-static-semantics-isvalidsimpleassignmenttarget) (like in your example) and properties.

Comment: Why would they allow such a syntax though. Would there be any particular use case where this might be helpful instead of confusing?

Comment: @JIXiang I don't know - especially since it's not allowed around all patterns (e.g. object destructuring where it would be useful). Maybe it's just a lapse that happened when defining the arrow function parameter cover grammar. You should ask at es-discuss.

Answer (score 15):

As per [@dlatikay's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43969489/why-is-foo-bar-legal-in-javascript#comment74969136_43969489), following an existing hunch, research into [`CoveredParenthesizedExpression`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-static-semantics-coveredparenthesizedexpression) yielded a better understanding of what's happening here.

Apparently, the reason why a non-terminal cannot be found in the [spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-left-hand-side-expressions), to explain why `(foo)` is acceptable as a `LeftHandExpression`, is surprisingly simple. I'm assuming you understand how parsers work, and that they operate in two separate stages: **Lexing** and **Parsing**.

What I've learned from this little research tangent is that the construct `(foo)` is not technically being delivered to parser, and therefor the engine, as you might think.

### [Consider the following](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7tHGNrDowGA/hqdefault.jpg)

```
var foo = (((bar)));
```

As we all know, something like this is perfectly legal. Why? Well you visually can just *ignore* the parenthesis while the statement remains making perfect sense.

Similarly, here is another valid example, even from a human readability perspective, because the parentheses only explicate what [PEMDAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) already makes implicit.

```
(3 + ((4 * 5) / 2)) === 3 + 4 * 5 / 2
>> true
```

One key observation can be loosely derived from this, given an understanding of how parsers already work. (remember, Javascript still is being parsed ([read: compiled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation)) and *then* run) So in a direct sense, these parentheses are *"stating the obvious"*.

### So all that being said, what exactly is going on?

Basically, parentheses (with the exception of function parameters) are collapsed into proper groupings of their containing symbols. IANAL but, in lay man's terms, that means that parentheses are only interpreted to guide the parser how to group what it reads. If the context of the parentheses is already "in order", and thus does not require any tweaking of the emitted [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), then the (machine) code is emitted as if those parentheses did not exist at all.

The parser is more or less being lazy, assuming the parens are impertinent. (which in this edge-case, is not true)

### Okay, and where exactly is this happening?

According to [12.2.1.5 Static Semantics: IsValidSimpleAssignmentTarget](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-semantics-static-semantics-isvalidsimpleassignmenttarget) in the spec,

> PrimaryExpression: (CoverParenthesizedExpressionAndArrowParameterList)
>
> 1. Let expr be CoveredParenthesizedExpression of CoverParenthesizedExpressionAndArrowParameterList.
> 2. Return IsValidSimpleAssignmentTarget of expr.

I.E. If expecting `primaryExpression` return whatever is inside the parenthesis and use that.

Because of that, in this scenario, it does not convert `(foo)` into `CoveredParenthesizedExpression{ inner: "foo" }`, it converts it simply into `foo` which preserves the fact that it is an `Identifier` and thus syntactically, **while not necessarily lexically**, valid.

## TL;DR

[It's wat.](http://destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat)

**Want a little more insight?**

Check out [@Bergi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43970003/877165).

Comment: Thanks @dlatikay! You help me find exactly what I was needing in order to confirm my nagging suspicions.

Comment: "Why? Because you can just ignore the parenthesis while the statement remains making perfect." --- this actually needs a reference to the standard.

Comment: @zerkms Nowhere in the spec, so far as I can imagine, says this in plain terms. [CoverParenthesizedExpressionAndArrowParameterList](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-static-semantics-coveredparenthesizedexpression) mentioned in answer, does imply this behavior however.

Comment: Then the answer is a speculation `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` Behaviour **must** be explainable by the standard, otherwise it's either implementation specific, or a bug, or an undefined behaviour.

Comment: Took a closer look, [CoveredParenthesizedExpression](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-static-semantics-coveredparenthesizedexpression) does explicitly state this production will return the 'lexical token stream' found within itself. Understanding what that means, the given behavior is explained. Did tweak the link, as per your comment though.

Comment: What is weird though is that they didn't allow `({ … }) = …`, i.e. a destructuring expression in parenthesis.

Comment: @Bergi can you help find how it denies it? From https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-semantics-static-semantics-isvalidsimpleassignmenttarget it looks like it should be fine. Where is the other tricky part?

Comment: @zerkms Exactly there - it yields `false` for object literals, they're no *simple* assignment target. (A test in Chrome confirmed I understood it right :-D)

Comment: @Bergi but curly braces in `{ ... } = ` is not an object literal, but an object destructuring syntax. Or apparently it does not have a context outside of the parentheses.

Comment: Parentheses are parser tokens, not just lexemes, and they are not used to 'force the lexer ...  how to group what it reads`. The parser does all that. The fact that the production you mention is reached via the parentheses proves it.

Comment: @zerkms That's exactly why this cover grammar stuff is so confusing :-/ It really is an *ObjectLiteral* in the grammar (not an "object initialiser" though) - they even [note](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-object-initializer-static-semantics-early-errors) it: "*ObjectLiteral productions are also used as a cover grammar for ObjectAssignmentPattern*". And in [the evaluation](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation), they reparse it as an *AssignmentPattern*. No idea why it's that complicated.

Comment: Out of curiosity I found [this](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/lr-1-grammar-parser-and-lookahead-restrictions) and [that](http://2ality.com/2012/04/arrow-functions.html). The reason for cover grammars is that they simplify writing a parser. Apparently they forgot the user story "Reading and underrstanding the spec".

Comment: This answer sounds wrong - it's not correct that "parentheses are only interpreted to force the lexer how to group what it reads".  That ("grouping" things into the correct AST) is the job of the parser, not the lexer.

Comment: Edited to reflect @EJP's suggestions