# SyntaxError: Invalid destructuring assignment target or ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have this code example:

```
var a = 10;
({a}) = 0;
```

In Google Chrome, it shows an error: `SyntaxError: Invalid destructuring assignment target`

In Firefox, it shows an error: `ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side`

Actually, I would like to understand what kind of error it is?

Comment: What did you expect that code to do?

Comment: @Pointy just testing the language

Comment: Well the language is telling you that that's wrong :) The `( )` are wrong, and the right-hand side is not an object so that's wrong too.

Comment: Because you're using an incorrect syntax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: It's still interesting that both browsers throw different errors.

Comment: @Terry If I need, I will write the correct code. Just re-read my main question.

Comment: It turns out I was wrong; it is in fact possible to destructure into already existing variables. All you have to do is: `({ a } = { a: 42 })`. Note that the parentheses have to go around the entire assignment expression, not just the LHS.

Comment: @Terry ok write the next code: `var a = 10; ({a} = 0;)` There will be no error

Comment: Which was precisely the syntax suggested in the MDN article I linked...?

Comment: @MaximPro This results in a `SyntaxError`, at least in Firefox. The grammar doesn't allow for destructuring assignments where new variables aren't being declared without wrapping the whole assignment expression in parentheses. (re: the unedited version of your comment, `var a = 10; {a} = 0;`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it's simply invalid syntax. You [are not allowed](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-assignment-operators-static-semantics-early-errors) to put a destructuring pattern in parentheses<sup>[1]</sup>:

> It is an early Reference Error<sup>[2]</sup> if *LeftHandSideExpression* is neither an *ObjectLiteral* nor an *ArrayLiteral* and IsValidSimpleAssignmentTarget of *LeftHandSideExpression* is `false`.

The `({a})` you have as a *LeftHandSideExpression* is a *ParenthesizedExpression*, not an *ObjectLiteral*, and the parenthesis don't contain a simple assignment target.

You probably are looking for [a parenthesised statement to allow the destructuring pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27386234/1048572):

```
var a = 10;
({a} = 0);
```

<sub>1: Surprisingly, [`(a) = 0;` is a valid statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43969489/1048572) though.</sub>
<sub>2: It seems that Chrome is wrong by throwing a `SyntaxError` then</sub>

Comment: Hmm, if this is a syntax error, then where to look for its error in ecmascript?

Comment: I mean, If is it SyntaxError then it is early error. Where I can find?

Comment: `It is a Syntax Error if LeftHandSideExpression is neither an ObjectLiteral nor an ArrayLiteral and
IsValidSimpleAssignmentTarget(LeftHandSideExpression) is false.` on page 281.

Comment: @JonasWilms I understand correctly that this part of the code `({a})` from `({a}) = 0` is perceived as AssignmentPattern

Comment: @MaximPro No, parentheses are not permitted in the productions of *AssignmentPattern*