# Why`()` changes `this` in function call

Tags: javascript, this, comma-operator

> Talk is cheap; show me the code.

```js
// equals to this.test = "inside window"
var test = "inside window";

function f () {
  console.log(this.test)
};

var obj = {
  test: "inside object",
  fn: f
};

obj.fn();      // "inside object"   --> fine
(obj).fn();    // "inside object"   --> fine
(1, obj).fn(); // "inside object"   --> fine
(obj.fn)();    // "inside object"   --> fine
(0 || obj.fn)(); // "inside window"   --> why?

// reference equality check
console.log(
  f === obj.fn && 
  (obj.fn) === f && 
  f === (1, obj.fn)
); // all equal :/
```

I had read ydkjs book and Im familiar with call-site and dynamic `this` binding, but I don't understand why the last function call has `window` as its `this` context; in this controlled experiment that only thing
that is changed `()` and `comma operator` and as you can see in the last statement `comma operator` is doing something weird. I suspect it does an assignment when it returns the value *(since if we do an assignment the same result happens)* but I'm not sure.

## UPDATE:

The effect is also seen on `&&`, `||` operators: `(0 || obj.fn)()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given:

```
foo.bar()
```

Inside `bar`, `this` will be `foo`.

(There are exceptions, such as when `bar` is defined with an arrow function, but they don't apply in this case).

Given:

```
const bar = foo.bar;
bar();
```

Now the function has been called without the context of `foo` so `this` is now the default object (which is `window` in a browser).

The expression: `(1, foo.bar)` evaluates as the right-hand side. This is the function.

Just as if you had copied it to a variable, this disconnects the function from the object before you call it, so you get the same effect.

There's no assignment because you haven't involved a variable, but you are calling the *result of an expression* and not the object method directly.

Comment: hmmm, intersing; *this disconnects the function from the object before you call it, so you get the same effect.* but how is it different from `(a.fn)();`

Comment: Is it right to say that you can think of `(1, a.fn)();` as `(function(){ 1; return a.fn;}())();`? And `(a.fn)();` simply becomes `a.fn();`.

Comment: @Leonardo `(a.fn)` has no coma operator, it's just `a.fn`, brackets don't cause evaluation

Comment: @Kaddath so no `evaluation` happens when you parenthesis around something, like `(2)`? only `comma operator` evaluates?

Comment: @Leonardo parenthesis only control the order the actions are made, it doesn't prevent things to be evaluated if it needs to, for example in `var a = (1 + 1) * 2;` things are avaluated. In `(1, a.fn)();` the parenthesis only assures that the coma operator is made before the function call. The coma operator is not the only thing that causes evaluation

Comment: @Kaddath It's not that simple. In theory `()` creates an expression context so that things inside it are evaluated as an expression. For example `() => {return 1}` is not evaluated as an expression therefore `() => {return 1}()` is a syntax error. However `()` forces an expression context so that `(() => {return 1})()` is an IIFE. Do you know where in the spec does it allow `(a.b)` to not be an expression and not evaluated? If you can, can you explain why it seems to be evaluated and returns `b` such that `(a.b)()` calls `b`?

Comment: Hey there, I found this place can very correctly explain what's going on. https://2ality.com/2015/12/references.html

Answer (score 6):

To support @Quentin's answer, the comma operator indeed returns the last operand as a  **function without context** (hence window) rather than the one from the object's blueprint.

Only on calling apply/call over the function with the object, it can gain the context back.

```
(1, a.fn).call(a);  // "inside object"
(1, a.fn).apply(a); // "inside object"
```