# type error: can not read property 'get ' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
const URL= require("url").Url;
const URLSearchParams= require("url");
var http=require("http");
var url_string = "http://www.example.com/t.html?a=1&b=3&c=m2-m3-m4-m5";
 var url = new URL (url_string);
var c = url.searchParams.get("a");
console.log(c);
```

Hi I am new to javascript, I have gone through the answer for

> [How to get the value from the GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters)

I have run the above code but iam getting

```
Type error: cannot read property get of undefined.
```

I was not able to find the answer anywhere. Can someone please help me and tell me what my mistake is?

Comment: The error is telling you that `.searchParams` is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you use :

```
const URL= require("url").Url;
```

[NodeJS documentation for the URL module](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_class_urlsearchparams) says :

```
const { URL } = require('url'); // No .Url and with { }

const myURL = new URL('https://example.org/?abc=123');
console.log(myURL.searchParams.get('abc'));
```

**Edit**

`const { URL }` is called [destructuring assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26999820/javascript-object-bracket-notation-navigation-on-left-side-of-assign).

This code works for me, tested in Node v7.9 :

```
const { URL } = require("url");
const URLSearchParams= require("url");
var url_string = "http://www.example.com/t.html?a=1&b=3&c=m2-m3-m4-m5";
var url = new URL (url_string);
var c = url.searchParams.get("a");
console.log(c); // logs : 1
```

Comment: @nuy5 What version of node are you running? `node -v`

Comment: iam using version 6.11.0

Comment: @nuy5 The `new URL` API was only added in v7. You need to either use the legacy API, or upgrade Node.

Comment: Oh right!! @nuy5 what version of Node are you using? Maybe you just need to install the latest version (7.something as of now)

Comment: i have upgraded to 8.1.3 but it is showing the same error

Comment: I have added a working and tested example, answer edited.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation of 'url'](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_searchparams) , it looks like the URL object should be upper case:

```
const URL= require("url").URL;
```

Comment: if URL is used in upper case  it is giving an error:  URL is not a constructor