# javascript: meaning of curly brace between variable name

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I am extremely weak with javascript due to its lax syntax but very punishing special characters meaning.

In `react-native-navigation` [tutorial](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/headers) there is this snippet

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
   const {state, setParams} = navigation;
   const isInfo = state.params.mode === 'info';
   const {user} = state.params;
   return {
     title: isInfo ? `${user}'s Contact Info` : `Chat with 
 ${state.params.user}`,
     headerRight: (
       <Button
         title={isInfo ? 'Done' : `${user}'s info`}
         onPress={() => setParams({ mode: isInfo ? 'none' : 'info'})}
       />
     ),
   };
 };
```

Originally, I mistakenly type the third line as this:
`const {isInfo} = state.params.mode === 'info';`

and my code doesn't work.

What is the difference with:
`const isInfo = state.params.mode === 'info';`

since the next line, there is curly brace wrapping `{user}`

it is very confusing for me, but these kind of minor thing is notoriously difficult to Google, so sorry and thanks in advance!

Comment: Please check this ref link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26999820/javascript-object-bracket-notation-navigation-on-left-side-of-assign

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Essentially curly braces like you've mentioned are Objects in javascript.

So making something like this in javascript

```
const user = {
    name: 'bob',
    age: 23,
};
```

Is making a user Object which you can use like this: `user.name` which will return `bob`.

With ES6 you're capable of making Objects from other Objects.

```
const {user} = state.params;
//user will be state.params.user
```

The above is basically pulling the property `user` from the object `state.params` into a new variable. Really all they're doing is making it so you don't have to write `state.params.user` each time and rather you can write `user`.

There's some other cool stuff you can do with this above technique. You can 'merge' arrays and objects into new constants which is pretty cool.

```
const test = {
    ...user,
    anotherProperty: 'value',
};
```

With react and redux (if you're using it) you'll see a lot of this: `Object.assign({}, state, {});` which is used to create a new object with the previous properties of the state overwritten with the new state (because redux requires a new object). This is kind of the same as using `{...state, ...newState}`.

Please someone remind me what this `...Object` method is called?

This line `const isInfo = state.params.mode === 'info';` is a shorthand for declaring a bool. `isInfo` will be either true or false depending on whether `state.params.mode === 'info'`.

To translate the above into C++ for you

```
if (state.params.mode === 'info') {
    bool isInfo = true;
else {
    bool isInfo = false;
}
```

I can't remember if there is a similar Object array in C++ as in JavaScript bit think of Objects in JavaScript as Arrays with defined keys. That way the above `{...state, ...newState}` is like an 'override' of keys. So

```
int y = [1,2,3];
int x = [3,2,1];


for (i=0;i<=2;i++) {
    y[i] = x[i];
}
```

Something like that I think?

Comment: I see! This is a very clear explanation! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Zennichimaro I'm not very good with the name of things as you can tell ^^^ been thrown into this ES6 env so I know how you feel! (y)

Comment: lol, yeah.!! There is a whole lots of things I see in javascript that I don't understand but can't Google!! (and yes, I use redux!!) oh no... I don't get your 'advanced' stuff as well, hope someone reminds you, lol

Comment: lol, worse thing is I'm from c, c++ background where everything is pretty rigid and there is only one way of doing things (no shorthand), hahaha

Comment: @Zennichimaro haha :p what languages are you used to? I'll try translating? Essentially it's making a new object from 2 other objects. if `state = {param: '1'}` and `newState = {param: '2'}` then `return {...state, ...newState}` will return an Object `{param: '2'}`

Comment: @Zennichimaro I tried to translate this into C++ for you. Think it's correct?

Comment: I see! I think it is exactly like `Dictionary.Merge` in csharp, you will get a new `Dictionary` that contain the values combined from both `state` and `newState` right?

Comment: No idea! lol but yea it's like the combination of both Objects where newState's properties are overriding the state properties :) hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

In ES6 you can deconstruct objects into different variables. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

> The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that
>   makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from
>   objects, into distinct variables.

Answer (score 4):

This is the ES6 syntax, The expression `const {user} = state.params;` is equal to `const user = state.params.user;` and the `const {isInfo} = state.params.mode === 'info';` will result in `{isInfo: undefined}`.
For more information you can see [here](https://babeljs.io/learn-es2015/#ecmascript-2015-features-destructuring).