# What's the meaning of const {a,b} = await foo();

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand this alexa skill but I've never seen this:

```
const {
      playbackInfo,
      playbackSetting,
    } = await handlerInput.attributesManager.getPersistentAttributes();
```

You can find on line 48 [here](https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-audio-player/blob/mainline/multiple-streams/lambda/src/index.js). Also at line 42 is not clear.
What's the meaning when I see something like `const {a,b} = await foo();` or `const {a,b} = foo;` I always seen `const = something`. I couldn't find it in the new ES6 features.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript object bracket notation ({ Navigation } =) on left side of assign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26999820/javascript-object-bracket-notation-navigation-on-left-side-of-assign) as listed on [this reference question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549780/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-javascript).

Comment: https://medium.com/dailyjs/asynchronous-adventures-in-javascript-async-await-bd2e62f37ffd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) `handlerInput.attributesManager.getPersistentAttributes()` returns a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).

2) [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) waits for the promise to be resolved

3) `const { a, b }` [deconstructs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the object that is returned when the promise is resolved.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, the destructuring assignment. I don't know why I didn't find it before asking. My bad.