# What does it means declaring an array as a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This doubt comes from [React Hooks Tutorial](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) and it's particulary strange for me:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
```

The order is important when declaring? What name receives this sort of declaration? Since what version of ES this syntax was launched?

Comment: Here's another similar question with a useful answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26999820/javascript-object-bracket-notation-navigation-on-left-side-of-assign

Answer (score 1):

That's [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). `useState` returns an array with three values, `count` will then get the value of the first array entry, `setCount` of the second and so on.