# Why React useState return const array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am currently learning React and React hook. A classic example of using useState is as below:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
```

My question is why the returned array is const? I think at least the value of count is changed over time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript object bracket notation ({ Navigation } =) on left side of assign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26999820/javascript-object-bracket-notation-navigation-on-left-side-of-assign) and [What is destructuring assignment and its uses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54605286)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is destructuring assignment and its uses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54605286/what-is-destructuring-assignment-and-its-uses)

Comment: You're not supposed to mutate state. In order to correctly update your values, you should use `setCount()`  to update the value of `count`. I believe you may destructure it using `let` or `var` but using `const` helps prevent mutation.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The value returned by `useState` is not a const array, rather its just an array which the user has decided to declare as `const`. Think of the above as

```
const stateValue = useState(0);
const count = stateValue[0];
const setCount = stateValue[1];
```

So in short, the syntax `const [count, setCount] = useState(0);` is an [`Array destructuring syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring).

Not its is declared as `const` because you are not reassigning `count` or `setCount` to something else in your code, instead just using `setCount` method to update the state count.

---

React authors decided to return an array with `state value` and `state setter` so that you can name it anything you want instead of using a pre-decided name while destructuring.

Comment: "so that you can name it anything you want instead of using a pre-decided name while destructuring" that is answer I was looking for!

Comment: If useState would return an object then the names would be fixed, which means you cannot have multiple occurrences of useState in the same component.

Comment: Aah, the naming makes sense, so even though you could have used an alias like const { value: myValue, setter: setMyValue} = useState, that would have been annoying for all the useStates you are likely to use in a component