# (React fetch data)what is the difference between these two

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables, fetch, constants

I am very new to the coding world. I am creating a meme generator and fetching data from the api. The below is part of the code, there is a const {memes} to store the data fetched from api, but why do I need it?
Why can't I put it like this --> this.setState({allMemeImg: response.data})

```
    componentDidMount(){
        fetch("https://api.imgflip.com/get_memes")
        .then (response => response.json())
        .then (response => {   
            const {memes} = response.data 
            this.setState({allMemeImg: memes})
                })
    }
```

Comment: That's called a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring). It's the same as doing `const memes = response.data.memes`. Without it, you'd do `this.setState({ allMemeImg: response.data.memes })`. It's not required - it's just syntactic sugar for your convenience.

Comment: You can. just ```setState({allMemeImg: resopnse?.data?.memes})```

Comment: @cybercoder I'd argue that `?.` changes the semantics a little bit :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript object bracket notation ({ Navigation } =) on left side of assign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26999820/javascript-object-bracket-notation-navigation-on-left-side-of-assign)

Comment: @cybercoder the `?` do not change anything here actually.

Comment: Question Mark operator is needed to prevent error when there's no nested key or object, and returns ```undefined``` instead of error.

Answer (score 0):

the line `const {memes} = response.data` is using destructuring syntax to assign `response.data.memes` to a constant `memes`. it is equivalent to saying `const memes = response.data.memes`. you could skip it and do `this.setState({allMemeImg: response.data.memes})`

Answer (score 0):

Your API returns an object with more parameters where memes is one of them. With this syntax `const {memes} = response.data`  you extract only the memes property. You can skip this and use directly `this.setState({allMemeImg: respone.data.memes})`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const { memes } = response.data;
```

is the same as

```js
const memes = response.data.memes;
```

You could even do this:

```js
const { data: { memes }} = response;
```