# React Router protected routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, router, protected

I'm learning React Router (protected routes, to be precise) and in React Router documentation  there is a function which I almost understand but there is one line of code which I can't see how it works. Maybe someone can shortly describe what that line does. Below  is a function from https://reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow

```
function LoginPage() {
  let history = useHistory();
  let location = useLocation();

  let { from } = location.state || { from: { pathname: "/" } };
  let login = () => {
    fakeAuth.authenticate(() => {
        history.replace(from);
    });
  };
```

What does this line do?

```
let { from } = location.state || { from: { pathname: "/" } };
```

I understand that we are creating an object but what does `||` do? Is it connecting two objects into one? I don't get it.

Comment: This is nothing to do with protected routes, React Router or even React. It's destructuring, with a default value provided to destructure out of in the case that `location.state` is null or undefined. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/2802055/3001761 for the right-hand side, https://stackoverflow.com/q/26999820/3001761 for the left-hand side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`||` is the logical OR operator

```
let { from } = location.state || { from: { pathname: "/" } };
```

This is saying, assign `location.state.from` to the variable **from** if `location.state` is not null or undefined, else assign `{ pathname: "/" }`