# arr1 = [1, 2, 3] const { length } = arr1 is going to output 3, how is this works?

Tags: javascript

so basically i found out that if we create array for example arr1 = [1, 2, 3] and new const { length } = arr1; will going to output 3 but how is this works exactly? is there any more operators instead of { length }? and what are the other use of using const { here some stuff } syntax? i do some research but i didnt find anything that points out this syntax. any assumptions?

Comment: `[1, 2, 3]` in javascript is vaguely a shortcut to `{"0": 1, ..."length": 3}`

Comment: Duplicate of [Javascript object bracket notation ({ Navigation } =) on left side of assign](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26999820/4642212). See [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9549780/4642212) and the documentation on MDN about [expressions and operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators).

Answer (score 1):

Basically this is **Object destructuring**

*Basic example:*

```
const user = {
    id: 42,
    is_verified: true
};

const {id, is_verified} = user;

console.log(id); // 42
console.log(is_verified); // true
```

In your case:

```
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3]

arr1.length = 3
// Or,
const { length } = arr1
```

To know more: [Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring)

Answer (score 1):

Let examine each line of code :)

```
const arr1 = [1,2,3];
```

Here, you define an array "arr1", which has 3 elements, so arr1's length is 3.
In javascript, `arr1` is an object, and 1 of its properties is "length", which reflects the length of the array. So, arr1.length = 3

Now the second line :

```
const {length} = arr1
```

Here, we use destructuring assignment to get the property "length" from object `arr1`. This line is equal to :

```
const length = arr1.length;
```

which give you length = 3

Make sense?

You can read more about the destructuring assignment here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: *a destructive method* wrong. It's called *destructuring assignment* and has nothing to do with *destroying*.

Comment: sorry, will fix it :)

Comment: It's not a *method*, it's an assignment.